# XSL cross-reference

Tags: xml, xslt, cross-reference

I'm learning XSL right now and have a question regarding cross-references.
My target XML file is structured like this:

```
<XML>
    <Model>
        <packedElement typ="class" id="1"/>
        <packedElement typ="class" id="2"/>
        <packedElement typ="class" id="3"/>
    </Model>
    <Elements>
        <Element idref="1">
            <Attributes comment="comment 1."/>
        </Element>
        <Element idref="2">
            <Attributes comment="comment 2."/>
        </Element>
        <Element idref="3">
            <Attributes comment="comment 3."/>
        </Element>
    </Elements>
</XML>
```

I want to connect id=idref. My goal is to list all packedElements and print their comment.
Can u guys help me?

I tried to resolve it with the key-funktion, but I wasn't very succesful.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="CommentK" match="Element" use="@idref"/>


<xsl:template match="XML">
<XML>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</XML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Start" match="packedElement">
<xsl:variable name="TEST" select="@id"/>
<xsl:variable name="Comment">
<xsl:call-template name="FindComment">
<xsl:with-param name="test2" select="@id"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<content comment="{$Comment}" id ="{@id}" test="{$TEST}"></content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FindComment">
<xsl:param name="test2"/>

<xsl:for-each select="key('CommentK', '$test2')">

<xsl:value-of select="Attributes/@comment"/>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT version is 2.0. (Btw can someone tell me the difference between the .XSLT and .XSL?)

Comment: What did your attempt look like? What did you want the result to look like?

Comment: I think your attempt would have almost worked, except that you used `'$test2'` which is the _string value_ "$test2". It should have been just `key('CommentK', $test2)`. I do think the `FindComment` and `for-each` are overkill though. Martin Honnen's answer is a good one.

Comment: To answer the question at the end of your post, .XSL and .XSLT are both typical file extensions for XSLT files and it should make no difference which one you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="el-by-idref" match="Elements/Element" use="@idref"/>

<xsl:template match="XML">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Model/packedElement"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Model/packedElement">
  <content comment="{key('el-by-idref', @id)/Attributes/@comment}" id="{@id}" test="{@id}"/>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that way you get

```
<XML>
   <content comment="comment 1." id="1" test="1"/>
   <content comment="comment 2." id="2" test="2"/>
   <content comment="comment 3." id="3" test="3"/>
</XML>
```